# Discrete Integration of a 1st Differenced Logged Series in R

Tags: r, integration, difference

I have a 1st differenced logged series that I need to convert back to the original level units. How do I do this in R?

Below is my data series, their respective transformations, and attempted code:

Original Series:

```
 o <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Logged Series:

```
l <- c(0.693, 1.099, 1.386, 1.609, 1.792, 1.946, 2.079, 2.197, 2.303)
```

1st Differenced, Logged Series:

```
dl <- c(-0.693, -1.792, -2.485, -2.996, -3.401, -3.738, -4.025, -4.277, -4.500)
diffinv(dl, differences = 1)
```

Desired output:

```
 [1]  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Attempted Code:

```
x <- c(1:10)
lx <- log(x)
dlx <-diff(lx)


diffinv(dlx, differences = 1)
```

Current Output:

[1] 0.0000000 0.6931472 1.0986123 1.3862944 1.6094379 1.7917595 1.9459101
 [8] 2.0794415 2.1972246 2.3025851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to remember your definitions. `e ^ (ln (x)) = x` , therefore

```
exp(diffinv(dlx, differences = 1))
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Now assumed my original series was a continuous series, i.e.:

o <- c(1.1, 2.6, 3.6, 4.8, 5.1, 6.0, 7.3, 8.8, 9.4, 10.5)

l <- log(o)
dl <- diff(l)


exp(diffinv(dl,  differences = 1))


When carrying out this same code, I get a different result than the original series:

 [1] 1.000000 2.363636 3.272727 4.363636 4.636364 5.454545 6.636364 8.000000
 [9] 8.545455 9.545455


Why is this?

Comment: @Darlene Take a look at `?diffinv`. You can set initial values there, which is why the same code wasn't working. You need to specify the initial value. When integrating, there's always a constant. In the first case, that was just 0, so we didn't need to specify it. In this case we do. `exp(diffinv(dl, differences = 1, xi = log(1.1)))`